# jquery.signalr not recognizing jquery

Tags: jquery, signalr

I am new to using SignalR. I have set up Asp.Net (not core) SignalR on the server side.

Now, on my client that is already built on React (using Typescript), I am trying to connect to the various hubs.

I have installed the SignalR version from:

npm install signalr

These are the imports in my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import signalr from "signalr";
```

However, I am consistently running into this error when loading jquery.signalr.js:

**jQuery was not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before the SignalR client JavaScript file**

I have tried a lot of solutions posted online such as trying to add these lines before loading the JS (or actually even adding it inside of jquery.signalR.js)

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
var $ = require("jquery")
```

etc.

But none of these work.

I have updated my loaders as well but no luck.

```
rules: [
            {
                test: require.resolve("jquery"),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "expose-loader",
                        query: "jQuery",
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "expose-loader",
                        query: "$",
                    },
                ]
            }]
```

I have also updated the signalr.js file, as it is not resolving to the right jquery.js files.

I have updated this as follows.

Also, note before I come into signalr.js file, the $ is defined, but originally the function below had signature

```
(function ($, window, undefined) {
```

I changed it to another variable below. Now $ is at least defined, but its type is resolving as "function" which is a string and not a real function.

```
/// <reference path="../jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../jquery/dist/jquery.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.signalR.version.js" />
(function (k, window, undefined) {
```

I will really appreciate if someone can tell me what to do here and what am I doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out? Having same issue.

Comment: no we moved to another solution.